# Retrieve first image from a Wagtail Streamfield for blog_index_page

Tags: json, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

Assume I am following the **[Your first Wagtail site](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.7/getting_started/tutorial.html)** tutorial, except I want to use a Streamfield, instead of separate **RichTextField** or **BlogPageGalleryImage**.  For example :

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
```

... becomes ...

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(classname="full title")),
        ('intro', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('body', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
    ], null=True, blank=True,)
```

How can I (or can I) pull the first image and the beginning of **intro** (...as I cannot restrict length) from a Streamfield for use in the blog_index_page.html template, and avoid using separate fields and **BlogPageGalleryImage** Class?  Therefore replacing this template :

```
{% for post in blogpages %}
{% with post=post.specific %}
    <h2><a href="{% pageurl post %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>

    {% with post.main_image as main_image %}
        {% if main_image %}{% image main_image fill-160x100 %}{% endif %}
    {% endwith %}

    <p>{{ post.intro }}<p>
{% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

With something more like this :

```
{% for post in blogpages %}
{% with post=post.specific %}
    <h2><a href="{% pageurl post %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>

    {{ post.body.image.first() }}

    <p>{{ post.intro.get_words(50) }}</p>
    {{ post.body|richtext }}
{% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this part of the docs?  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/streamfield.html#template-rendering

Comment: Yes, i can unpack an entire Streamfield.  However for the index page I only need the first element of each block type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same exact question 5 years later, so hopefully it helps when somebody stumbles upon it. Solved it by making a method in `BlogPage` class that checks if there are image blocks in the body (StreamField) and retuns the first image from the first image block.

```
def first_body_image(self):
    image_blocks = [block for block in self.body if block.block_type == 'image']
    if not image_blocks:
        return None
    return image_blocks[0].value
```

And you can use it in a template with image tags

```
{% image post.specific.first_body_image fill-300x300 %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I no longer work with Wagtail but this might come in handy again one day.